# Efficient SQL query to fetch records from a View

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, query-performance

SQL Server 2012

I have a DataSource which is a view which contains more records (say 50000 records and more). I have a stored procedure which will be selecting from this view.

View (`vw_Info`) has columns

```
Machinename, m_Start, m_end, m_status
```

I will pass the user defined table type with below 2 columns as input

```
Machinename  LastTimeStamp
```

Sample

```
create table #tmp (MachineName nvarchar(50), LastTimeStamp datetime)

insert into #tmp (MachineName, LastTimeStamp) 
values ('A01', '2017-12-21 06:29:13.027'), ('A02', '2017-12-21 06:29:13.027'),
       ('A03', '2017-12-21 06:29:13.027')
```

I need to select all the records from the view which matches the MachineName and M_Start > lasttimestamp

My query

```
select 
    a.MachineName, fc.m_start, fc.m_end 
from 
    #tmp A
inner join 
    (select * from vw_Info) fc on a.MachineName = fc.machineName 
                               and fc.m_start > a.LastTimeStamp
```

Will this be an efficient SQL query? I will be using a service to call this stored procedure query, to fetch records every 1 minute.

Please suggest

Comment: why not examine the execution plan, and tell us what you see?

Comment: Views don't "contain" records.  How many rows in the underlying tables?  What is the view definition?  What is the partition and index structure of the underlying tables?

Comment: You can use the view as if it were a table in your query, so no need for the "(select * from vw_info) fc", just use "vw_info fc".  Will this be efficient, nope, it's using a non-equi join, and this can never be truly efficient.